# how to get number containing rows in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have tried regexp, regexp_like and like but didn't work

**select * from b**

- where regexp_like(col1, '\d')
- where regexp_like(col1, '[0-9]')
- ....etc

**we have this table**

| Col1 |
| --- |
| avr100000 |
| adfdsgwr |
| 20170910020359.761 |
| Enterprise |
| adf56ds76gwr |
| 0+093000 |
| 080000 |
| adfdsgwr |

***output should be these 5 rows***

```
  col1
  avr100000
  20170910020359.761
  adf56ds76gwr
  0+093000
  1080000
```

***Thanks***

Comment: Please see the note I added in my answer about performance testing using `regexp_count` vs. `regexp_instr` to do this check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_instr` in the where clause to see if it finds a digit anywhere in the string:

```
create temp table b(col1 string);

insert into b (col1) values ('avr100000'), ('adfdsgwr'), 
('20170910020359.761'),
('Enterprise'),
('adf56ds76gwr'),
('0+093000'),
('080000'),
('adfdsgwr')
;

select col1 from b where regexp_instr(col1, '\\d') > 0;
```

I'm updating my answer to note that `regexp_instr` is going to perform about 3.8 times faster than using `regexp_count` for this requirement.

The reason is that `regexp_instr` will stop and report the location of the first digit it encounters. In contrast, `regexp_count` will continue examining the string until it reaches its end. If we only want to know if a digit exists in a string, we can stop as soon as we encounter the first one.

If it is a small data set, this won't matter much. For large data sets, that 3.8 times faster makes a big difference. Here is a mini test harness that shows the performance difference:

```
create or replace transient table RANDOM_STRINGS as
select RANDSTR(50, random()) as RANDSTR from table(generator (rowcount => 10000000));

alter session set use_cached_result = false;

-- Run these statements multiple times on an X-Small warehouse to test performance
-- Run both to warm the cache, then note the times after the initial runs to warm the cache

-- Average over 10 times with warm cache: 3.315s
select count(*) as ROWS_WITH_NUMBERS 
from RANDOM_STRINGS where regexp_count(randstr, '\\d') > 0;


-- Average over 10 times with warm cache: 0.8686s
select count(*) as ROWS_WITH_NUMBERS 
from RANDOM_STRINGS where regexp_instr(randstr, '\\d') > 0;
```

Comment: Good point on regexp_instr stopping on the first occurrence of a number - vs regexp_count inspecting the entire string to produce a full accounting of numeric values in the inspected string.  This should be the preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to count how many alpha tokens there are:

```
select column1 as input
    ,regexp_count(column1, '[A-Za-z]') as alpha_count
from values
    ('0-100000'),
    ('adfdsgwr'),
    ('20170910020359.761'),
    ('Enterprise'),
    ('adfdsgwr'),
    ('0+093000'),
    ('1-080000'),
    ('adfdsgwr')
```

| INPUT | ALPHA_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 0-100000 | 0 |
| adfdsgwr | 8 |
| 20170910020359.761 | 0 |
| Enterprise | 10 |
| adfdsgwr | 8 |
| 0+093000 | 0 |
| 1-080000 | 0 |
| adfdsgwr | 8 |

and thus exclude those where it is not zero:

```
select column1 as input
from values
    ('0-100000'),
    ('adfdsgwr'),
    ('20170910020359.761'),
    ('Enterprise'),
    ('adfdsgwr'),
    ('0+093000'),
    ('1-080000'),
    ('adfdsgwr')
where regexp_count(column1, '[A-Za-z]') = 0
```

gives:

| INPUT |
| --- |
| 0-100000 |
| 20170910020359.761 |
| 0+093000 |
| 1-080000 |

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is find 1 or more instances of a numeric value:

```
select
    column1 as input
from
values
    ('avr100000'),
    ('adfdsgwr'),
    ('20170910020359.761'),
    ('Enterprise'),
    ('adf56ds76gwr'),
    ('0+093000'),
    ('1-080000'),
    ('adfdsgwr')
where
    regexp_count (column1, '\\d') > 0;
```

Results:

```
avr100000
20170910020359.800
adf56ds76gwr
0+093000
1-080000
```